# Use of tr:hover in CSS

Tags: css

Just working on a Wordpress site & making some changes to the style.css to impact on tables within the site.

It's tables of class 'lassa' and the edits I've made are:

```
table.lassa {
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #99cc00;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.lassa th {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #99cc00;
background-color: #dedede;
}
table.lassa td {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #99cc00;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

table.lassa tr:hover {
background-color: Green;
}
```

...and it all works fine - except for the **tr:hover** bit

It's not even that important, but I'd like to know where I'm going wrong. I'm an SEO guy rather than out & out code junkie so always want to know *why* something isn't doing as I expect! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the background color is on the 'td' rather than the 'tr', the 'tr' element is effectively behind the 'td' element so you will never see its background color if the 'td' is set, change to the below:

```
table.lassa tr:hover td{
  background-color: Green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, most helpful - and to @Janko too, that lab is great to fiddle with.